# Flutter orientation change but textstyle does not change

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, material-design

I'm trying to set UI according to mobile orientation and it's working fine, but inside use the textstyle does not change after changing the mobile orientation.

I have used the "[OrientationBuilder](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/orientation)" to detect the orientation and also separated the both the UI and his textstyle properties. But when I change the landscape to portrait so all the UI change according perfectly but inside the use textstyle for text is not changed.

Comment: Any code sample might help to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `UniqueKey()` as a key for the `Text()` widget, which is used with the target `TextStyle()`